# dbpedia SPARQL query to get certain value's for a given city

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am sure what I want to do is very easy, yet I cannot seem to get the query right. I have records in dataset which have values such as city name e.g. 'New York' and it's corresponding country code e.g 'US'. I also have access to the full country name and country ISO codes.

I would like to get the population and abstract value's for these cities off dbpedia, by using a where clause such as:

```
Get population where name = "New York" and isoCountryCode = "US"
```

I've searched for help on this to no avail.

so far I have been kindly helped by @rohk with this query, which does not fully work for all locations:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?abstract ?pop
WHERE {
   ?city rdf:type schema:City ;
     rdfs:label ?label ;
     dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract ;
     dbpedia-owl:country ?country ;
     dbpedia-owl:populationTotal ?pop .
   ?country dbpprop:countryCode "USA"@en .
   FILTER ( lang(?abstract) = 'en' and regex(?label, "New York City"))
 }
```

The above works for New York, however when I change it to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?abstract ?pop
WHERE {
   ?city rdf:type schema:City ;
         rdfs:label ?label ;
         dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract ;
         dbpedia-owl:country ?country ;
         dbpedia-owl:populationTotal ?pop .
   ?country dbpprop:countryCode "THA"@en .
   FILTER ( lang(?abstract) = 'en' and regex(?label, "Bangkok"))
}
```

It returns no results for Bangkok, Thailand.

I just cant seem to get the SPARQL query correct, I'm sure I am being silly with my query. If any guru's could provide me with help I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query is working

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
WHERE {
   ?city rdf:type schema:City ;
         rdfs:label ?label ;
         dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract ;
         dbpedia-owl:country ?country ;
         dbpprop:website ?website ;
         dbpedia-owl:populationTotal ?pop .
   ?country dbpprop:countryCode "USA"@en .
   FILTER ( lang(?abstract) = 'en' and regex(?label, "New York City"))
}
```

EDIT : For Bangkok, there are 2 problems :

- No country code for Thailand : you can use `rdfs:label "Thailand"@en` instead.
- `rdf:type` of Bangkok is not `schema:City` but `dbpedia-owl:Settlement`

Here is a working query for Bangkok

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
WHERE {
   ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Settlement ;
         rdfs:label "Bangkok"@en ;
         dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract ;
         dbpedia-owl:populationTotal ?pop ;
         dbpedia-owl:country ?country ;
         dbpprop:website ?website .
   ?country rdfs:label "Thailand"@en .
   FILTER ( lang(?abstract) = 'en' )
}
```

Comment: Hi - thanks! As mentioned below, this seems to return the details of the state and not the city, is there any way to specify the Place type must be a city or town and not a state or country? Thanks again.

Comment: Deleted my comments and updated actual question with progress report, thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much, so it seems there is not one automated query I could make where I just pass the properties of the labels to a function.

Comment: Sorry one last question before I stop bugging you, how could I also retrieve the dbpprop:website property along with the pop for a city? As you can see I am a total newbie. Thanks again.

Comment: @Paul : you have to add it in your where clause... answer updated

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want something like this:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?x rdfs:label "New York City"@en.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:populationTotal ?pop.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
}
```

To get only the English abstract, add a `FILTER`:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?x rdfs:label "New York City"@en.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:populationTotal ?pop.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
  FILTER (LANG(?abstract) = 'en')
}
```

“New York” is the state and it doesn't have a `populationTotal` figure attached. “New York City” is the city.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was hoping there was perhaps a way to specify the place type as being a city or town?

Comment: There are multiple ways, none of them work perfectly and it depends on the kind of thing you want to filter for. Check the values of the `rdf:type`, `dcterms:subject` and `dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate` properties for something that reliably selects the entities you want. Adding a line like this to your query could work: `?x rdf:type dbpedia-owl:City.`