# Query cities and their country from dbpedia

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, dbpedia

I'm trying to construct an ontology in OWL for countries and cities(If such an implementation already exist, please point it to me)

To get the data, I'm trying to use sparql with the following code:

```
SELECT ?c WHERE {
   ?c rdfs:label ?name .
   ?c dbpedia-owl:country <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Country> .
}
```

I'm a newbie in sparql and dbpedia. The above code is not returning me all cities and the country they are situated in. I really to need to use dbpedia to achieve this.

any suggestion?

Comment: Have you checked [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904938/dbpedia-sparql-query-to-get-certain-values-for-a-given-city) ?

Comment: I modified the query from you link and got this one SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?country
WHERE {
   ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:city ;
     rdfs:label ?label ;
     dbpedia-owl:country ?country 
 } but its still not working

Comment: This one is working but I'm getting lots of irrelevant results:

SELECT *
WHERE {
 ?x rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Country
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SPARQL is case sensitive (because RDF is case sensitive). DBpedia uses the convention that property names are start with a lower case letter (e.g. `dbpedia-owl:country` for "the country belonging to X is ...") and class names start with an upper case letter (e.g. `dbpedia-owl:Country`).

If by *works*, I mean *returns results*, this works (`City` instead of `city`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?country 
WHERE { ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:City ; 
              rdfs:label ?label ; 
              dbpedia-owl:country ?country 
}
```

Be aware, however, that not all places that you and me would call cities are defined as a `dbpedia-owl:City` - they may be of class `dbpedia-owl:Settlement` or other classes. So the above query may not yield all cities you want.

Also: to construct an ontology, you don't need "the data". An ontology defines for example that all cities are populated places, and that all populated places are places. To be able to say that, you don't need to know that Edinburgh is in the United Kingdom.

Comment: thanks for replying, in fact, for this ontology, I only need like containement for performing query expansion, so if I can know, all places that is it another place, this can help me, whether is a settlement or a city, its not really an issue, what is very important for me is like A contain B and C. C contains D...... Is it possible to get this info from dbpedia??

Comment: So you're constructing a *knowledge base*. I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here; the given query shows that you can find the country that a city is in: "United Kingdom" contains "Edinburgh", ...

Comment: do you think if we extend the query suppose like instead only city, perform a union of (city,owl:Settlement,place,..), would it not be better??

Comment: It depends on what you want to know. Do you only need the country that a city is in? Or do you want to include the province, or state, or region if they are defined for the city?

Comment: in this situation I only need to know which is what, its going to be enough. By the way, is there a place where they describe the graph structure of dbpedia??

Comment: If you're looking for the DBpedia ontology, it's [here](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/dbpedia.owl). More info is [here](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/How_to_edit_the_DBpedia_Ontology), but you should also look at pages for things manually and see what properties and links are available.

Comment: I've added a question concerning the containment relationship between United Kingdom and England, if you can have a look, that would be great, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650341/dbpedia-get-relationship-between-united-kingdom-and-england

Comment: Update `dbpedia-owl` with `dbo`.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code on https://dbpedia.org/sparql

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?country 
WHERE { ?city rdf:type dbo:City ; 
        rdfs:label ?label ; 
        dbo:country ?country 
     }
```