# How to get the relationship between United Kingdom and England from DBpedia?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to write a SPARQL query to obtain the relationship between the United Kingdom and England with no success: no result is returned, as you can see [here](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20?property%20%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/England%3E%20?property%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/United_Kingdom%3E%0D%0A%7D):

```
SELECT ?property  
WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/England> ?property <http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_Kingdom>
}
```

Any suggestion? Is there any mistake between in the SPARQL query? How can I find through DBpedia that England is in the UK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is correct. If you get no results, there is no such relationship.

DBpedia is derived from available structured data on Wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/England shows no property in the Infobox on the right that links England to the UK. If you look up a resource in your browser, e.g. http://dbpedia.org/resource/England, you get all information known about the resource.

Comment: you know this lookup facility by dbpedia http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString=panda, do you know whether it is possible to do the same thing with sparql and get the result set

Comment: You asked the same question as a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667133/dbpedia-sparql-search-similar-to-dbpedia-lookup-facility

Answer (score 0):

On the specific question of a relationship between DBPedia's England and United Kingdom, it might be best to look at them the other way around:

```
SELECT *
WHERE { 
{ 
   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_Kingdom> ?property <http://dbpedia.org/resource/England>
}
```

...and find that ?property gets bound to rdfs:seeAlso.

There is also the `Category:` resources in DBPedia, which use SKOS-based broader and narrower relationships, see for example:

```
SELECT ?property ?object 
WHERE {
   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:England> ?property ?object .
}
```