# DBpedia SPARQL search similar to DBpedia lookup facility

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

DBpedia offers a look up facility like http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString=panda that returns a result set. Can the same result set be obtained by using SPARQL to query DBpedia

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927643/work-around-to-query-dbpedia-for-two-keywords answer your question? Or the [description of the lookup services](http://dbpedia.org/lookup)?

Comment: Yes, completely, I was thinking about one thing with dbpedia, with the lookup service or the rdf for querying, it returns many results, but within the API, is there any service that allows calculating the similarity between between two terms, I've googled but did not find it

Comment: "Yes, it completely answers my question"? "rdf for querying" = SPARQL? What do you mean by "similarity between two terms"? Please, be precise when you ask things! :)

Comment: ohhh, yeah, you right this is a different question in itself :P